# ExtJs simulate TAB on ENTER keypress

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I know it is not the smartest idea, but I still have to do it.
Our users want to use ENTER like TAB.
So, the best I came up with is this:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Base, {
            initComponent: function() {
                this.callParent(arguments);

                this.on('afterrender', function() {
                    var me=this;
                    this.getEl().on('keypress',function (e){
                        if(e.getKey() == 13) {
                            me.nextNode().focus();
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

But it still does not work exactly the same way as TAB.
I mean, it works OK with input fields, but not other controls.
May be there is some low-level solution.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In the past I've attached the listener to the document, something like this:

```
Ext.getDoc().on('keypress', function(event, target) {

    // get the form field component
    var targetEl = Ext.get(target.id),
        fieldEl = targetEl.up('[class*=x-field]') || {},
        field = Ext.getCmp(fieldEl.id);

    if (
        // the ENTER key was pressed...
        event.ENTER == event.getKey() &&

        // from a form field...
        field &&

        // which has valid data.
        field.isValid()

        ) {

        // get the next form field
        var next = field.next('[isFormField]');

        // focus the next field if it exists
        if (next) {
            event.stopEvent();
            next.focus();
        }                   
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of Ext is this for? I suppose, not ExtJS 4.x

Comment: @mik This is working for me in 4.1.0. I realized that I was not using it for form fields though, and form field events don't target the component so that would not have worked. I edited my answer so it works for form fields specifically.

Answer (score 1):

For Ext.form.field.Text and similar xtypes there is a extra config `enableKeyEvents` that needs to be set before the keypress/keydown/keyup events fire.
The `enableKeyEvents` config option needs to be set to true as it's default to false.

[ExtJS API Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-enableKeyEvents)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert on ExtJs.

That said, maybe try something like:

```
if (e.getKey() === 13) {
    me.blur();
    return false;  // cancel key event to prevent the [Enter] behavior
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
if (e.getKey() === 13) {
    e.keyCode = Ext.EventObject.TAB
    this.fireEvent(e, {// any additional options
   });
}
```

Haven't really tried this ever myself.